# Seamless texture for large object

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, texture-painting

Hey guys I'm working with very large object I created a texture with substance designer . It seems okey when look closer but while looking environment it is obvious that it is repeated too much [image: For example]. I could not fıgure it out how to solve that problem thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you share some more screen shots of your texture settings and uv mapping, etc. so that we can see if there is anything we can suggest there? I am not sure here if I am seeing the texture in the viewport as a background and that little plane is the object, or if the object is in the background and the square is actually a texture brush stencil, etc.

Comment: Textures of repeating patterns need only one module, the rest is wasteful. Overlay the grunge part as a separate texture, possibly a procedural one instead.

Comment: Actually I'm modelling a cargo ship its very big object and I want it looks very realistic but cant figure how to texture big models